# Yii - How to add custom field to form that can be accesed in controller?

Tags: php, forms, yii, controller

I have a Yii form based off a database model/table that I now want to add a custom field too that can then be accessed in the corresponding controller.

So the custom field DOES NOT correspond to a column in the database table.

Can this be done? If so how?

My motivation for doing this is to add a form value that I check, and I only process the form IFF that form value is empty. The field is hidden using CSS, so humans won't see it, and will hopefully be a simple convenient way to minimize spam. Since a bot is likely to fill out the form indiscriminately.
[CAPTCHA Alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471031/are-there-any-alternatives-to-recaptcha-net-for-stopping-spam/#471142)

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between start & end of rendering your form insert `hidden` (for example) next:

```
<?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('hidden_secret',''); ?>
```

Than in controller:

```
$hidden_secret = Yii::app()->request->getParam('hidden_secret'));
```

Comment: Worked a treat! VG + MT!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add simple property to model:

```
class User extends CActiveRecord {
    public $myField;
}
```

Also do not forget to add its field in rules() if so required

Comment: i haven't tried this, if it offers an advantage over the answer above I will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: answer above do no based on Model form